# Use Kendo Jquery in PHP Symfony Project

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So, ive downloaded Kendo for Jquery and im trying to import it to my Symfony application.

I added the css files and JQuery as well as kendo.all js file to the head of my main twig. It looks like this:

```
<head>
     <!-- Common Kendo UI CSS for web widgets and widgets for data visualization. -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/kendo_css/kendo.common.min.css') }}">
            <!-- Default Kendo UI theme CSS for web widgets and widgets for data visualization. -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/kendo_css/kendo.default.min.css') }}">


            <script src="{{ asset('build/kendo_js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

            <script src="{{ asset('build/kendo_js/kendo.all.min.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```

Now, if I try and do inline javascript for kendo grid like this:

```
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [{
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name"
        },
            {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name"
            }],
        dataSource: {
            data: [{
                FirstName: "Joe",
                LastName: "Smith"
            },
                {
                    FirstName: "Jane",
                    LastName: "Smith"
                }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

(this is all in my base twig) it is working.

But, if I try and add it to a new js file and import that js file in another twig that extends base twig(basically, everything is loaded css and js, jquery, kendo and my custom js file) I cannot access the kendoGrid method. It says:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).kendoGrid is not a function TypeError: $(...).kendoGrid is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/admin/users/index_js.js:10456:16)
    at mightThrow (http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/admin/users/index_js.js:3609:29)
    at process (http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/admin/users/index_js.js:3677:12) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.js:3818
jquery.js:3827 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoGrid is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:4)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3534)
    at process (jquery.js:3602)
```

Other twig looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


    {% block javascripts %}
        {{ parent() }}
        <script src="{{ asset('build/admin/users/index_js.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}

{% block base_body %}

<div id="grid" class="row">

        </div>


{% endblock %}
```

and custom js file is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [{
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name"
        },
            {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name"
            }],
        dataSource: {
            data: [{
                FirstName: "Joe",
                LastName: "Smith"
            },
                {
                    FirstName: "Jane",
                    LastName: "Smith"
                }]
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well you had better show this other twig file so we can see what you have done

Comment: @RiggsFolly please see edited

Comment: So next question: Does your `base.html.twig` have a `javascripts` block that can be overridden?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, it does, the js file gets called, but it does not recognize kendo inside it